# why in my method onActivityResult it does not reach the else if condition. I want to save cropped image to firebase using the UCrop

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ucrop

why in my method onActivityResult it does not reach the else if condition. I want to save cropped image to firebase using the UCrop

Uri imageUriResuktCrop;

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == CODE_IMG_GALLERY) {

        imageUri = data.getData();
        if (imageUri != null) {
            startCrop(imageUri);

        }

    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP  ) {

        imageUriResuktCrop = UCrop.getOutput(data);

        if (imageUriResuktCrop != null) {
             img.setImageURI(imageUriResuktCrop);

        }
    }


    if (!currentImg.toString().equals("")) {
        StorageReference delRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(currentImg.toString());
        delRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });

    }


    StorageReference mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads").child("gallery");
    fileRef = mStorageRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(imageUriResuktCrop));
    StorageTask mUploadTask = fileRef.putFile(imageUriResuktCrop)
            .addOnSuccessListener((OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>) taskSnapshot -> {



                fileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {

           //code here


}
```

Comment: replace else if with else

Answer (score 0):

The result sending activity has not set the result equal to RESULT_OK. Remove the check to verify the result